# Boto3 SES email - showing HTML code in email client

Tags: python, boto3, amazon-ses

I am trying my hand at AWS SES and I have below code to send email

from boto3 import client

```
conn = client('ses',region_name='us-east-1')
conn.send_email(
                Source=from_addr,
                Destination={'ToAddresses': 'x@x.com'},
                Message={
                    'Subject': {'Data': self.subject,'Charset': 'UTF-8'},
                    'Body': {
                        'Text': {'Data': 'Hello','Charset': 'UTF-8'},
                        'Text': {'Data': '<html>Hello</html>','Charset': 'UTF-8'}
                    }
            }
        )
```

The email is sent out but in the email client I am seeing HTML code rather than HTML email. I am wondering where to add content-type as the documentation doesn't have that info.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've used the `Text` field twice - the second one should be `Html`:

`conn = client('ses',region_name='us-east-1')
conn.send_email(
                Source=from_addr,
                Destination={'ToAddresses': 'x@x.com'},
                Message={
                    'Subject': {'Data': self.subject,'Charset': 'UTF-8'},
                    'Body': {
                        'Text': {'Data': 'Hello','Charset': 'UTF-8'},
                        'Html': {'Data': '<html>Hello</html>','Charset': 'UTF-8'}
                    }
            }
        )`

See the documentation [here](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ses.html#SES.Client.send_email)